# Running system commands remotley using UFT 12

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I have recently upgraded from QTP 11 to UFT 12 the new testing tool from HP.
My question may seems quite generic.
Is it possible to use UFT API testing features to run system commands remotely in different machines?

I explain : I have a machine A with UFT installed on it and I have 4 other machines B,C,D,E
I would like to use the A machine in order to access into each machine remotely and run a local command on the destination machine.
As I need to run theses in many machines is possible to automate it with UFT?

Thanks
Zied

Answer (score 1):

QTP/UFT scripts are essentially just a series of commands that are being executed.  If you run that script remotely on another machine, you've successfully executed those commands on a remote machine instead of locally.

Even though QTP/UFT is primarily used for testing, anything you write in the script will be executed on the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easy way would be to run the scripts through ALM on remote servers A,B,C etc instead of A trying to access B,C and henceforth.